# Swift background downloadTask doesn't call willPerformHTTPRedirection

Tags: ios, swift, background, foreground, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am having an issue where using a background urlsession, and my `willPerformHTTPRedirection` doesn't get called:

```
private class BackgroundCachingDelegate: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate
{
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest) async -> URLRequest?
    {
        //... Never gets called
    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
private func createNewBackgroundSession()
{
    let backgroundCachingConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: OfflineCacheService.entityBackgroundSessionIdentifier)
    backgroundCachingConfiguration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    let backgroundCachingDelegate = BackgroundCachingDelegate(/*params*/)
    self.backgroundCachingSession = URLSession(configuration: backgroundCachingConfiguration, delegate: backgroundCachingDelegate, delegateQueue: nil)
}
    
private func startRequest(url: URL)
{
    if self.backgroundCachingSession == nil
    {
        self.createNewBackgroundSession()
    }
        
    var request = self.uiViewController.getURLRequest(method: "GET", url: url)
    request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringCacheData
    self.backgroundCachingSession!.downloadTask(with: request).resume()
}
```

The code works if I take the redirected URL directly and try using that.

I also know for sure the server is performing a redirect:
[image]

Any ideas?

**Update**

Also maybe to mention, I do get a response of 0 bytes back with the redirected url as the response url. I could have an edge case based on the above and call the new redirected url, but I'd prefer the correct approach if that's not it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background url sessions are handled by the operating system, not your app process. Therefore there are some limitations on how they operate.

In particular, [redirections are always followed](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background)

> - Redirects are always followed. As a result, even if you have implemented [`urlSession(_:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate/1411626-urlsession), it is not called.

So, the delegate method not being called is the expected behaviour. You need to investigate why you are not getting any data from the redirection.

Comment: Thought I would add here, I think the reason I was getting 0 bytes is because I was using an authorization header, which in C# gets cleared when a redirect is followed, assuming this perhaps happens in swift/iOS too and hence the redirect gets followed but without the authorization header

Comment: That would certainly make sense.